# Using URI Routing Wildcards

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In my controller called **article** I have the following function, which I am using to display data from my database:

```
function get_all(){

  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'article/get-all';
  $config['total_rows'] = 2; // example
  $config['per_page'] = 1;
  $config['num_links'] = 20;
  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination" align="center">';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);

  $this->load->model('mod_articles');
  $data['records']= $this->mod_articles->get_articles_this_year($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

  $this->load->view('view_article_list',$data);
}
```

Generally the url to reach the function is: `http://localhost/article/get_all` , but to make the url look like this `http://localhost/article/get-all` , in config/route.php I have added the following line:

```
 $route['article/get-all'] = "article/get_all";
```

It is working fine, but when I click on pagination link to go to next page, it shows **404 Page Not Found**

Could you please tell me how to use the URI Routing Wildcards properly ?

### Edit

I also have the following in the config/route.php to avoid index to appear in the url

```
 $route['article/(:any)'] = "article/index/$1";
```

If I remove the above line, then the pagination works.

Answer (score 3):

Does the pagination class add any extra URI segments to the links?, for example:

`/article/get-all/page/5`

If, so, you should set up two routes something like:

```
$route['article/get-all'] = "article/get_all";
$route['article/get-all/(:any)/(:any)'] = "article/get_all/$1/$2";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't add any extra uri segments liked your mentioned. I hovered on the pagination link and I saw the url looks like this `article/get-all/1` . So I used this `$route['article/get-all/(:any)'] = "article/get_all/$1";` , but still its showing `404 Page Not Found` . Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see you include config for the `uri_segment`, pagination library uses this config.

`$config["uri_segment"] = 3;`

`$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;`

Use it as

```
 $data['records']= $this->mod_articles->get_articles_this_year($config['per_page'],$page);
```

directly attaching `$this->uri->segment(3)` in your query returns `NULL` since if a url segment is not valid it returns FALSE, and what the sql `limit` needs is integer where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I used your code but still its showing `404 Page Not Found`. :(

Comment: @black_belt when hovering on the links where does the link redirect you?

Comment: If I click on any of the pagination links it takes me to `article/error`. I forgot to mention that I also have this in my route.php `$route['article/(:any)'] = "article/index/$1";` if I remove this, then the pagination works. But I really need to get rid of index in the url. Thanks :)

Comment: if you want to get rid of `index.php` you need `.htaccess`

Comment: The index in `article/index/$1` is a function in a controller class :) I already got rid of index.php :)

Comment: yes you can remove it, but still when you want to navigate to it you still have to add index on your link still the links will appear. `routes` are just for routing not rewriting url